# Not Get data in jstree

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, jstree

I am create menu of Category and SubCategory in my project using jstree.
but i do not get or not show my data in jstree format.
so, what is problem.?
Plz Help me.
thnks....

My Controller Code

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetCatList()
    {
        IEnumerable<Category> cats = _CategoryBusiness.Select();
        return new JsonResult
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = cats
        };
    }
```

My Model Class

```
[Serializable]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Id")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int? SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubCategoryID")]
    public virtual Category SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

And _CategoryBusiness.Select() is

```
public List<Category> Select(int id = 0)
    {
        var selectFrom = _Ctx.Categories.Select(a => a);
        var query = selectFrom.Select(a => a);

        if(id > 0)
            query = query.Where(a => a.CategoryID == id);


        return query.ToList();
    }
```

And My View Page code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    FillJSTree();
});
function FillJSTree() {
    $("#onflycheckboxes").jstree({
        json_data: {
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Categories/GetCatList/",
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": "json",
                "contentType": "application/json charset=utf-8",
            }
        },
        //checkbox: {
        //    real_checkboxes: true,
        //    checked_parent_open: true
        //},
        plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]
    });
}
</script>
```

.
   .
   .
   .
   ..

```
  <div id="onflycheckboxes">
  </div>
```

Comment: 1 - Have you tried to open directly this adress /Categories/GetCatList/ to check if data is returned by the view ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Before sending data to view, serialize that. This works for me. P.s. Your category data must be tree node.

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetCatList()
{
    IEnumerable<Category> cats = _CategoryBusiness.Select();
    string myjsonmodel = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(cats);
    return myjsonmodel;
}
```